# separate .cpp file for every qml in blackberry 10

Tags: qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades, blackberry-qnx

1. In my application i am using navigation pane. and i want to make separate files for every QML
   Let suppose this is my file

---

applicationui.cpp

```
    // initial load    
    // Create scene document from main.qml asset, the parent is set
    // to ensure the document gets destroyed properly at shut down.
    QmlDocument *qml = QmlDocument::create("asset:///main.qml").parent(this);

    // Create root object for the UI
    AbstractPane *root = qml->createRootObject<AbstractPane>();

    // Set created root object as the application scene
    app->setScene(root);
```

---

2.Here i am loading **main.qml** which is like this

```
import bb.cascades 1.0

NavigationPane {
    id: navigationPane

    Page {
        titleBar: TitleBar {
            // Localized text with the dynamic translation and locale updates support
            title: qsTr("Page 1") + Retranslate.onLocaleOrLanguageChanged
        }

        Container {
        }

        actions: ActionItem {
            title: qsTr("Second page") + Retranslate.onLocaleOrLanguageChanged
            ActionBar.placement: ActionBarPlacement.OnBar

            onTriggered: {
                // A second Page is created and pushed when this action is triggered.
                navigationPane.push(secondPageDefinition.createObject());
            }
        }
    }

    attachedObjects: [
        // Definition of the second Page, used to dynamically create the Page above.
        ComponentDefinition {
            id: secondPageDefinition
            source: "DetailsPage.qml"
        }
    ]

    onPopTransitionEnded: {
        // Destroy the popped Page once the back transition has ended.
        page.destroy();
    }
}
```

---

3.And in this file I am calling **"DetailsPage.qml"** file which look like this

```
import bb.cascades 1.0

Page {
    titleBar: TitleBar {
        // Localized text with the dynamic translation and locale updates support
        title: qsTr("Second Page") + Retranslate.onLocaleOrLanguageChanged
    }
    Container {
    Label {
        id: msgLabel
        objectName: "msgLabel"
    }   
    }
}
```

---

step 1: how to create seperate .cpp and .hh file for DetailsPage.qml

step 2: I want this becasue i am doing networking operations in .cpp and .hh and designing in QML.

step 3: The main reason i am confuse here is if i navigate from QML then total control is with QML and vice versa. On stack first qml can recognize its c++ file but if stack increases then how we should do that.

-------Please let me know If you don't understand my problem----------------

---

Comment: Get your answer from this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547550/what-is-this-control-and-how-to-use-it-in-bb-10-cascades-for-navigation/18588282#18588282

Comment: @ZuzooVn I convert my all network operations in QML.

Comment: But yes there is a solution in this example [link](https://github.com/RileyGB/BlackBerry10-Samples/tree/master/WebImageViewSample) .

Comment: Can we create seperate .cpp and .hpp file for .qml?

Comment: You can make a separate file for any function/Method and then register it inside your main.cpp and use it any where inside your project. it is easy as you can see the "WebImageview" project

Answer (score 0):

You can use call function in applicationui.cpp from .qml file by using  :

> qml->setContextProperty("_app", this);

If you want using different file .cpp you can use :

```
DetailPage detailPage = new DetailPage();

qml->setContextProperty("_detail", detailPage);
```

In .qml file, you can call function from .cpp by `_app.nameFunction() or _detail.nameFunction()`

Comment: No the issue is Consider the stack MAINSCREEN.qml<<FIRSTPAGE.qml<<SECONDPAGE.qml<<THIRDPAGE.qml. now THIRDPAGE.qml is at the top here how can i connect it with THIRDPAGE.cpp

Comment: @kernald please can you look my problem again

Answer (score 0):

1. Get sample app from my github samples for your query....

   https://github.com/svmrajesh/BB-10-Cascades/tree/master/MY%20APPS/stackNavigation
2. See following post to get solution

   [what is this control and how to use it in BB 10 cascades for navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547550/what-is-this-control-and-how-to-use-it-in-bb-10-cascades-for-navigation/18588282#18588282)